# Offset error while using react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view in android

Tags: react-native, keyboard

unable to perform any events after using react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view.

I am getting offset error in my emulator

```
<KeyboardAwareScrollView bounces = {false}
            style = {{marginBottom:"7%"}}
            scrollEnabled={true}
            keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'always'}
            stickyHeaderIndices = {[0]}
            enableOnAndroid={true}
            enableAutomaticScroll={(Platform.OS === 'ios')}
            extraScrollHeight={this.state.extraScrollHeight}
          >
```

[image]

Comment: Share your code

Comment: updated code above